# How to prevent loading a page from address bar?

Tags: php, captcha

I have a `game captcha`, which i want to place on a separate page.
When captcha is resolved - user will be redirected to the page with registration form.
So, only way to rich the form - should be - `via captcha page`, and the question is: How to prevent user to rich the form page from address bar ?
Maybe - to create a SESSION variable on a captcha page, `as a ticket for form page`, and then destroy that variable at the end of form page... but I'm not sure - is there a better way ?

Comment: Place the captcha on the registration page? Why do you want a captcha page?

Comment: @Laurence, there is no room enough for booth. The captcha game is full screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use AJAX to load the registration form dynamically after they have passed the captcha.

Comment: Piontek, with the ajax, will the form be loaded on the same page, or on the separate one ? Because, this is a full screen captcha.

Comment: I guess he wants captcha to prevent spamming. This way it only irritate people. He needs validation on the server, otherwise you could create a spambot.

Comment: On the same page - you could have it replace the CAPTCHA. So for example if you had all of the code for your CAPTCHA wrapped in a div with an ID of "main", you could pull in the registration form with AJAX and remove all of the contents of div#main, and then injecting the HTML for the registration form in that same div.